# using Revalee.client to send email at background

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Where should I call the revalee method to send mail email  at background? What I am trying to achieve is to send email to the client if the expiration date is coming. I have follow the link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/738753/Scheduling-tasks-with-Revalee-and-MVC

My actionmethod is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult SendExpirationMessage(int VehicleID)
    {
        // Validate the incoming request to ensure that this web app requested this callback
        if (!RevaleeRegistrar.ValidateCallback(this.Request))
        {
            // Return a '401 Unauthorized' response to the Revalee service if the callback doesn't validate
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = db.UserVehicleViewModels.Find(VehicleID);
        var span = user.TaxDate.AddYears(1).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        int days = span.Days;
        if (days >= 7)
        {

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
            new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("abc@abc.com", "Web Registration"),
            new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(user.Email));
            m.Subject = "Tax Notification";
            m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0} <BR/>This is an email to notify you about the due tax date of your vehicle, please pay tax on time. Thank you\" title=\"User Email Confirm\"></a>",
                user.UserName);
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@abc.com", "password");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(m);
        }
```

the helper method is:

```
    private void ScheduleExpirationMessage(int VehicleID)
    {
        // The server address where the Revalee service is installed
        string revaleeServiceHost = "192.168.1.4";

        // The callback will occur 27 days from now
        DateTimeOffset callbackTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1.0);

        // The url that will be called back, including userId
        Uri callbackUrl = new Uri(
            string.Format("http://localhost/UserVehicle/SendExpirationMessage/{0}", VehicleID));

        // Register the callback request with the Revalee service
        RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallback(revaleeServiceHost, callbackTime, callbackUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Have you installed & configured the Revalee Server (it is a Windows Service that is separate from the Revalee Client)? The Revalee client requires the server component and the client web application (where the Revalee.Client package is installed) will reference the Revalee server from its the `web.config`. For more information, visit the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com/) website.